# Celery: enqueuing multiple (100-1000) tasks at the same time via send_task?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, kombu

We quite often have the need to enqueue many messages (we chunk them into groups of 1000) using Celery (backed by RabbitMQ). Does anyone have a way to do this? We're basically trying to "batch" a large group of messages in one [send_task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/base.html#Celery.send_task) call.

If i were to guess we would need to go a step "deeper" and hook into `kombu` or even `py-amqp`.

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to "go deeper" and use Kombu directly. - There are few solutions that are suitable for different use-cases:

- You may want to exploit the [chunks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks) if you prefer using Celery workflows.
- There is nothing stopping you from calling send_task() thousands of times.
- If calling send_task() is too slow, you may want to use a pool of threads that would concurrently send N tasks to the queue.

Comment: Good points! I would prefer not to use chunks since these are large tasks (5-25 minutes processing time) and that would require re-engineering how we process them. I will mark this as the answer and simply call send_task continuously using pooling.

Answer (score 1):

What I - provisionally at least - ended up doing was making sure to keep the celery connection open, via:

```
with celery.Celery(set_as_current=False) as celeryapp:
    ...
    with celeryapp.connection_for_write(connect_timeout=connection_timeout) as conn:
        for message in messages:
            celeryapp.send_task(...)
```

That way I don't have to re-create connections for producing for each message.